# Drag To Select Calendar in Android with Compose

Tags: android, calendar, gesture

I'm trying to implement drag to select dates in my custom Calendar in Android which I've built using jetpack compose.

Here's the rough structure of my compose calendar:

Here's the vertical scrolling calendar:

```
fun VerticalCalendar(
    modifier: Modifier,
    props: VerticalCalendar.Props,
    onDateSelected: (CustomCalendar.Selection) -> Unit,
    onMonthAppear: ((LocalDate) -> Unit)?
) {
    Column(modifier) {

        // ....

        LazyColumn(
            Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            lazyListState,
        ) {
            verticalCalendarItems(
                props,
                onDateSelected,
                onMonthAppear,
                dragSelectedDates
            )
        }
    }
}


private fun LazyListScope.verticalCalendarItems(

    props: VerticalCalendar.Props,
    onDateSelected: (CustomCalendar.Selection) -> Unit,
    onMonthAppear: ((LocalDate) -> Unit)?,
    dragSelectedDates: MutableSet<LocalDate?>,

) = items(props.totalMonths, { it }, { 0 }) { index ->

    // .....

    Column() {
        
        Month(
            Modifier.padding(horizontal = CustomTheme.spacings.spacing4x),
            Month.Props(
                month,
                props.min,
                props.max,
                props.selection,
                props.disabledDates,
                props.weekDays,
                props.attachments,
                props.dateFormatter,
                props.accessibilityMode
            ),
            onDateSelected,
            onMonthAppear,
            dragSelectedDates
        )
    }
}
```

Each *Month* lays out it's own children as follows:

```
internal fun Month(
    modifier: Modifier,
    props: Month.Props,
    onDateSelected: (CustomCalendar.Selection) -> Unit,
    onMonthAppear: ((LocalDate) -> Unit)?,
    dragSelectedDates: MutableSet<LocalDate?>
) {

    Layout(
        {
            (1..props.month.lengthOfMonth()).forEach {

                //...

                Date(
                    Date.Props(
                        date,
                        date.toDateType(props.selection),
                        attachmentInfo,
                        isDisabled,
                        contentDescription,
                        stateDescription,
                        props.accessibilityMode
                    ),
                    onClick,
                )
            }
        },
        modifier,
        monthMeasurePolicy(indexOfFirstItem, Theme.spacings.spacing1x)
    )
}

private fun monthMeasurePolicy(
    indexOfFirstItem: Int,
    verticalSpacing: Dp,
) =
    MeasurePolicy { measurables, constraints ->
        val itemWidth = constraints.maxWidth / CustomCalendar.DAYS_IN_WEEK
        val itemHeight = CustomCalendar.DATE_ITEM_HEIGHT.toPx().toInt()
        val placeables = measurables.map {
            it.measure(
                Constraints(
                    minWidth = itemWidth,
                    maxWidth = itemWidth,
                    minHeight = itemHeight,
                    maxHeight = itemHeight
                ),
            )
        }
        val verticalSpacingPx = verticalSpacing.toPx().toInt()
        val rows =
            ceil((indexOfFirstItem + placeables.size).toFloat() / CustomCalendar.DAYS_IN_WEEK).toInt()
        val height =
            ((itemHeight + verticalSpacingPx) * rows) - verticalSpacingPx

        var x = itemWidth * (indexOfFirstItem)
        var y = 0
        val width = itemWidth * CustomCalendar.DAYS_IN_WEEK
        layout(width, height) {
            placeables.forEach { placeable ->
                placeable.placeRelative(x, y)
                x += itemWidth
                if (x == width) {
                    y += placeable.height + verticalSpacingPx
                    x = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Have been struggling to implement Drag-To-Select dates (just like in Google Photos). I referred to [this](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/create-a-photo-grid-with-multiselect-behavior-using-jetpack-compose-9a8d588a9b63) article but it was of little help since all the children are in LazyColumn.

But for my calendar, each Month is a child of lazy column + each Month has it's own children which are laid out using `Layout(...) { }`.

Can someone help here ?